# Automating downloading documents with R from a JavaServer Page

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a script to download files from a government weather site.

I haven't had much luck trying to do this in R. The site is:
https://agriculture.alberta.ca/acis/alberta-weather-data-viewer.jsp

Right now I'm looking at getting Solar Rad. at 2m but in the future will want to get other data as well.

I have been looking at r-bloggers but without much luck finding a way to do this. 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/short-r-tutorial-scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r/

Can R perform this task? If so could someone point me to a good reference source?

Comment: Does it change anything if the page is called alberta-weather-data-viewer.jsp or alberta-weather-data-viewer.html ?

Comment: Yes, the page with ".html" is "Page Not Found".

Comment: You didn't understand me. In your question title you wrote "from a JavaServer page", but if it would be another technology, your need is the same or not. You want to write an R script, or a JSP ?

Comment: you mean web scrapping (you just want the content once) or indeed automating, meaning periodically downloading and processing the data?

Comment: Yes, sorry I would like to periodically download and process the data for multiple sites/etc.